# Sed using regular expressions

Tags: sed

So basically I have a original list of 1500 names with a 4 digit number associated with each name. I have another file which contains 200 of these 1500 names with a new 4 digit number associated with it. I need to replace the old number with this new number.

I have a file original.txt which contains 1500 lines of text that looks like this:

> name AYxxxx
>
> name2 AYxxxx
>
> name3 AYxxxx
>
> ......
>
> name1500 AYxxxx

The xxxx is a 4 digit number, AY is a string that appears in front of every 4 digit character

I have an updated_file.txt that contains 200 lines like this:

> name AYzzzz
>
> name40 AYzzzz
>
> name1300 AYzzzz

zzzz is a different 4 digit number. I need to take that new number (zzzz) and replace the old number (xxxx) in the original.txt.

So in the original text, I need this is what the text should look like:

> name AYzzzz
>
> name2 AYxxxx
>
> name40 AYzzzz
>
> name1300 AYzzzz
>
> name1500 AYxxxx

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
names=updated.txt
while read names
do
    sed  -E "s/$names[^AY.*]/$names/" original.txt
done < "$names"
```

Comment: I guess no one has answerd, since it wery unclear what you like to do. Give better example on what the files contains.

Comment: Huh? You aren't doing a loop.

Comment: Consider editing  your post to include simple sample input file with bare minimum to describe all cases, and sample required output given the input. Please don't post as a comment, use the `{}` format tool at top left of edit box(as you seem to know already). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a sed script from the update field like

```
sed 's:\(.*AY\)\d\+:/\1/s_.*_&_:' UPDATEFILE > SEDUPDATE.SED
```

Then run the generated script on the original file like:

```
sed -f SEDUPDATE.SED ORIGINAL_FILE
```

Comment: I… Oh… Well… Oh… I'd never used that, but it looks very clever. I understood it at last, but maybe you could explain how it works for other people? That's an upvote for me anyway.

Comment: If you could explain how this works, it would be awesome. I tired it out and it didn't modify original_file at all.

Comment: Add an `-i` option to have `sed` modify a file in-place. Otherwise it will print the modified file to stdout.

Comment: If your `sed` supports `-f -` there is no need for a temp file.

Comment: @tripleee The output it prints out is incorrect. It prints to the terminal if I use the -f option. It prints one line repeatedly in which the the number has been updated correctly but it is missing the first character of the name. If I pass the -i option, I get /gsed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `S'.

Comment: If your actual input contains colons or underscores, that would be expected; but your example input does not exhibit anything like that.  However, it is possible that your `sed` does not recognize `\d` as a shorthand for `[0-9]` -- try substituting that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have upvoted @ZoltBotykai's answer but here is a minor modification which should hopefully be slightly more precise and portable.

```
sed 's:\(.*AY\)[0-9][0-9]*$:s_^\1[0-9]*$_&_:' updated_file.txt |
sed -f - -i original.txt
```

If you are on *BSD I believe you will need to add an empty argument to the `-i` option in order for it to work.  Remove this option while testing so you see the generated output on your screen instead of in the target file.

I tightened the regular expression somewhat and changed the `\d\+` (which is a recent Perl extension, for evolutionary scales of "recent") to something which should hopefully work even on HP-UX and the like.

On the other hand, some ancient `sed` implementations do not support the `-f` option with a dash to read the generated script from standard input; then, you'll need to revert to storing the generated script in a temporary file.

If your actual data contains underscores, you will have to use a different separator in the generated script.  The character after the `s` command can be anything, but the separator must not occur (unquoted) in the substitution regex or the replacement text.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
while read old new ; do
  sed -i "s/$old \([^ ]*\)/$new \1/" original.txt
done < updated_file.txt
```

**Warning:** with the `-i` option it will automatically update your `original.txt` file. Don't forget to make a backup copy first.

Comment: Please note that this can be really slow on huge files as it opens the (original) file (and seeks/searches) for every row in the updated_file.

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai Indeed, but there's no need for creating a temporary `sed` script. Everything depends on the size of files :-).

Comment: I get this error when I attempt to run the script:

gsed: -e expression #1, char 104: unknown option to `s'

Comment: I swapped the delimiter from / to | but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Trade a temp file for umpteen passes over the input? You can't be serious.

Comment: @tripleee Depending on size, again. I don't know for you, but if I have a dozen lines in my file, I won't bother creating another `sed` script. As soon as file size becomes high, I agree with you.